# NodeJS Reading Buffer Binary To Float

Tags: node.js, arrays, precision, endianness, bytebuffer

I have a large DAT file that holds custom byte information, 
And I've been tasked with converting the solution to JavaScript. 
It's to make the solution be more single-language and convert to serverless cloud computing.

But, I've run into an issue with converting this test data. 
The values supposed to return a float, 
But I can't seem to get the number converted correctly.

The sliced buffer output is `<Buffer 40 82 e2 31 d6 d7 2e 8d>`, 
Which is supposed to return `604.274335557087` 
But actually returns `4.090111255645752`.

And I'm at my wits end right now. 
Any thoughts?

```
  fs.readFile(file, (err, data) => {

...
      // Read other buffer slice() values fine until this step. 
      // Like: readInt8(), readIntBE(0, 4), readBigUInt64BE(0, 8) 
...

      let FloatNumber = data.slice(start, end).readFloatBE();
      console.log('FloatNumber', FloatNumber);

...

  }
```

Comment: `readFloatBE()` expects 32 bits input, but your sliced buffer is 64 bits. Shouldn't you be using `readDoubleBE()` which expects 64 bits.

Comment: Brilliant! I was just being braindead and taking the notes at face value 

Comment: Happy new year  

Comment: Happy New Year Bro 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const buf = Buffer.from([0x40, 0x82, 0xe2, 0x31, 0xd6, 0xd7, 0x2e, 0x8d]);

console.log( buf.readDoubleBE(0) );
// Prints: 604.274335557087
```